# Read Multipart data from HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

I got  below response after web request

```
--uuid:d48d8249-7aa7-4674-b023-3a332240f077
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
      <ns2:doTransferResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.vontobel.com/vai/ws/filetransfer" xmlns:ns3="http://www.vontobel.com/vai/vai_header_types">
        <serverFileSha1>
          <xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:6f0ab43e-e466-4074-a4df-e026aeb94f89-22324@cxf.apache.org"/>
        </serverFileSha1>
      </ns2:doTransferResponse>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
  --uuid:d48d8249-7aa7-4674-b023-3a332240f077
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
  Content-ID: <6f0ab43e-e466-4074-a4df-e026aeb94f89-22324@cxf.apache.org>

%!�9:���_}`��I��~P�
--uuid:d48d8249-7aa7-4674-b023-3a332240f077--
```

How do I read binary data in the content?